# logstash with an elastic search filter to nest related documents

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash

I would like to nest documents using logstash, but I need to run a query to find the id of the target document. For example, I have events with a time stamp and I want to nest them in target documents that specify a date range.

There is an elastic search filter plugin but it can only be used to search for past events, not an index of targets.

For example:

```
event {
  "datetime": "2016-01-01",
  "event": "something"
}

target1 {
  "start": "2015-01-01",
  "end": "2015-12-31"
}

target2 {
  "start": "2016-01-01",
  "end": "2016-12-31"
}
```

I would like to nest the event in target2 using logstash. I do not want to use a parent-child relationship for this data.

Thank you.

Comment: What is your past event you are searching? What is your current event? What is the target event you want to index?

Comment: I am using the couchdb_changes input plugin to index documents from couchdb. My event is a new or updated couchdb document; the target is another document that has already been indexed. My problem is to search for the right target document to nest the incoming document.

Comment: If your target documents only contain a start and end date to define a period, why not simply storing those two fields in your event documents (aka denormalization)?